# AngularJS - Ladda is undefined

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a similar issue to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256555/requirejs-dependency-not-working). But, I'm newbie to AngularJS. That's my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('learning',
[
    'ngResource',
    'ngMessages',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'angular-ladda',
    'jcs-autoValidate',
    'mgo-angular-wizard'
]);
```

I'm properly setting the scripts in index.html:

```
<script src="/src/bower_components/angular-ladda/dist/angular-ladda.js"></script>
<script src="/src/bower_components/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js"></script>
```

Index.html is using angular-ui-router. So I have a `<div ui-view="login">` which loads my login.html, below:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-group col-md-3 pull-left"
  ng-submit="authenticate()"
  novalidate
  name="loginForm">

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <label class="panel-title">Credentials</label>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-offset-0">
            <input type="text"
                   name="username"
                   placeholder="Username"
                   ng-model="login.user"
                   class="form-control"
                   required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-0">
            <input type="password"
                   name="password"
                   placeholder="Password"
                   ng-model="login.password"
                   class="form-control"
                   required>
        </div>

        <!-- ***** ERROR ***** -->
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
            ladda="login.isAuthenticating"> 
            Login
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have already logged `login.isAuthenticating` to see if was something with the controller, but the error I get is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` on Angular-ladda.js:

```
// create ladda button
var ladda = Ladda.create( element[0] );
```

Can anyone help me? Remember, I'm new to Angular.

Comment: the `ladda.min.js` needs to be loaded *before* `angular-ladda.js` in your index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load `ladda.min.js` before `angular-ladda.js`, as `angular-ladda.js` is going to use `ladda.min.js` implementation/`API`.

Correct sequence is below.

```
<script src="/src/bower_components/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/bower_components/angular-ladda/dist/angular-ladda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried the same sequence but its not working for me, the difference i see i dont have ladda.min.js in the dist folder and i am getting it from js folder